# We are disappointed of someone / disappointed from someone / disappointed in someone?

Tags: prepositions

When someone makes us disappointed. What preposition should we use idiomatically? In other words what are we?

> We are disappointed **of** him.

or

> We are disappointed **from** him.

or

> We are disappointed **in** him.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the list you provide, "in" is [the most idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=disappointed%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), but there's also "disappointed **by**", "disappointed **with**", and "disappointed **at**" a person or persons.

You can, apparently, be "disappointed **of**" some *expected result*, which can include the actions of some person.  However, to me this sounds formal and somewhat *archaic*, and I would never use use it.

As far as I know, "disappointed **from**" is not an idiomatic complement, although it may appear in an adjacent adverbial phrase:

> He was a malcontent, never happy, always complaining, and essentially **disappointed from** dusk to dawn.

[image]

Comment: I suppose *disappointed **of*** had more currency when it was thought to be syntactically analogous to ***proud, ashamed, afraid, fond, tired, unworthy...*** I must say it's striking that just a couple of centuries ago it was the second most common preposition to follow ***disappointed*** out of all your charted alternatives, but today it's by far the ***least*** common (and it just sounds "totally weird" to me, not merely "archaic" - something *only* a non-native speaker might come out with).

Comment: @Andrew. I do not deny the increasing use of acceptable alternatives when referring to  people. At this point, I remain adamant that 'in' is the best choice, although as you ngrams suggest, in a few decades my assessment may well be that it is one of several valid options.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   Why bother with what is clearly outside the lines? "disappointed of " is a no-go unless you're interested in historiical semantics....I think it gums up the works of a perfectly good answer, and, if you want to get into it, put up your own answer.

Comment: @RossMurray  Yes, I agree.  Use "in", at least until you get familiar enough with the alternatives to understand their subtle nuance.

Comment: Apart from it being an archaism, you need to look at the complement when **of** is used. It will be an intention, plan, scheme, or wish of some kind, not a person.    It means to be kept from achieving something.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm perfectly happy with Andrew's answer. I agree it's probably not relevant to most learners that I should be surprised how common ***disappointed of*** used to be - and that despite the fact that I must have read hundreds of books written in "Victorian English", the usage was completely unfamiliar to me. But my point about *syntactically analogous to **proud, ashamed, afraid, fond, tired, unworthy...*** might well be of interest to some learners, even if it's not important enough to justify a separate answer (or indeed, to justify Andrew adding anything to his actual Answer text).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the phrase is "disappointed **in** him."

Comment: @Perplexed folks, There are a range of prepositions in different situations that can be used after 'disappinted', but 'in' is always used for disappointment in a person or group or persons.

Comment: @RossMurray: It may be [far less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disappointed+with+you%2Cdisappointed+in+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20in%20you%3B%2Cc0), but I don't think you can say that ***I'm disappointed with you*** is somehow "incorrect". It's just a less common alternative preposition in such contexts.